# Why is timeout overridden?

Tags: javascript, dom, settimeout

```
const screenDiv = document.getElementById('screen');

function outputKorv() {
    const paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    screenDiv.appendChild(paragraph);
    const korv = new Array('k', 'o', 'r', 'v');
    let index = 0;
  
    while (index < korv.length) {
    const letter = document.createTextNode(korv[index]);
    setTimeout(console.log(letter), 1000);
    index++;
    }
}

outputKorv();
```

When I run the script the letters are written to the console immidiately, and not as I expected with a 1 second gap between them. I've also tried to put the increment in the timeout, but I can't get that to work either. I've tried: `setTimeout(index++, 1000)`, `setTimeout('index++', 1000)`, and `setTimeout(() => index++, 1000)`, but neither works. I've also tried a for loop, and do ... while, but I'm getting the same result with those too. The idea is to output the word 'korv' to an HTML-page one letter at a time. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to pass a function in timeout and not a statement, try with `()=>console.log(letter)`

Comment: `setTimeout(console.log, 1000, letter);` is also valid

Comment: also, setTimeout's don't wait for each other ... so when you do it right, all timeouts will trigger at about the same time

Comment: The idea is to make the loop pause after each character. I've tried to pass a function (`() => console.log(letter)`) as well but it's still outputting all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is: Make the function `async`, define a delay function as `const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))` and then simply call `await delay(1000)` at the point where you want to wait. This will greatly simplify the logic.

Here is the updated code. I took the liberty to also replace the verbose `while` loop with a `for` loop and get rid of the deprecated `new Array` syntax.

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const screenDiv = document.getElementById('screen');

async function outputKorv() {
    const paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    screenDiv.appendChild(paragraph);
    const korv = ['k', 'o', 'r', 'v'];
  
    for (let index = 0; index < korv.length; index++) {
      const letter = document.createTextNode(korv[index]);
      console.log(letter)
      await delay(1000);
    }
}

outputKorv();
```

Comment: Thank you, I made a recursive function that was working, but this is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be a recursive function instead of a loop.

Comment: This works but is more complicated to reason about and maintain. I recommend an asynchronous loop instead.